# How to check the return of a JavaScript function in onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

How to call a function inside onchange if the return of previous function is true,
what i am trying is calling many function on onchange event, but the last function should call if the return of previous function is true. my code is bellow:

```
<input type="text" name='test' id="test" onchange="remLdZero('test'); validatetest(); if(checkDuplicate('test', 'url','divid')===true){ nextfunction();};"  maxlength="10"  required>
```

my jvascript checkDuplicate() is below

```
function checkDuplicate(fieldId,page,msgArea){  
     var fieldVal= $('#'+fieldId).val();
     $.ajax({    
        type: "POST",
        url: page,
        data: fieldId+'='+fieldVal,    
        //dataType: "html",    
        success: function(data){
            if(data == 1){
                $('#'+msgArea).css("display","none");
                if(fieldId == 'test'){
                     return true;
                }
            }else{
                $('#'+msgArea).html(data);
                $('#'+msgArea).css("display","block");
            } 
       }
    }); 
 }
```

Note: If i call my `nextfunction()` instade of `return true` line, it works but as my nextfunction() brings a popup then browsers block the popup while if i call the nextfunction in onchange without checking the previous function it works.

Any soloution to fix it.

Comment: Since the Ajax-Request in checkDuplicate is asynchronous, and the success-method runs outside of checkDuplicate, there is no way you could get that return true value. Meaning: when checkDuplicate exits, and you check if it returns true, success has not run yet and the return is only for the success function.

Comment: The above comment is correct. If you want to do something depending on the result of an AJAX call, then the code that depends on it _must_ be in the "success" function of the ajax method (or in a function that's called from there). Or another way to create this kind of dependency is using jQuery Promises, which is a little more complicated.

Comment: Send the `nextFunction` as a callback function to your `checkDuplicate` function. Execute your callback function inside the success event of your ajax.

Comment: Also, you should put only one function call into the onchange event in your html, which then calls the other functions you want. Helps with readability for example

Comment: @HarryBomrah it works with chrome, but not with firefox anc ie

Comment: It should work with both. Please tell me how are u doing it?

Comment: Strange, firefox and even IE are capable of that task. It is quite common, too. I guess thats a problem in your code then somewhere.

Comment: @HarryBomrah i amde a function function callAkit(){
         phone_btn_onclick();
     }, then i call the callAkit() in my ajax succses

Comment: @barakataliforoz that is not right way to do it. Sorry for late reply.

Comment: @HarryBomrah can you help me with the right one as answer please,?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name='test' id="test" onchange="remLdZero('test'); validatetest(); checkDuplicate('test', 'url','divid', nextfunction);"  maxlength="10"  required>
```

**JS**

```
function checkDuplicate(fieldId,page,msgArea,callBakFn){  
 var fieldVal= $('#'+fieldId).val();
 $.ajax({    
    type: "POST",
    url: page,
    data: fieldId+'='+fieldVal,    
    //dataType: "html",    
    success: function(data){
        if(data == 1){
            $('#'+msgArea).css("display","none");
            if(fieldId == 'test'){
                 if(typeof callBakFn == "function"){
                     callBakFn();
                 }
            }
        }else{
            $('#'+msgArea).html(data);
            $('#'+msgArea).css("display","block");
        } 
   }
}); 
}
```

Now your `nextFunction` will only execute after your ajax request is done and ur result is `true`.